# How to run application/x-executable in nnn file manager?

Tags: xdg-open

I'm trying to open executable files in `nnn`. In my case the executable is the Telegram.
When I try to open it using `nnn` the firefox will open. I searched over the net and figure out I should set a default app to open this kind of files using `xdg-mime`.
I tried `xdg-mime` to discover the type of my executable:

```bash
[amirreza@localhost Telegram]$ xdg-mime query filetype Telegram 
application/x-executable
```

But I don't know what program should I use to open it. Isn't there a way to open `./Telegram`?

### More Info:

```bash
[amirreza@localhost Telegram]$ file Telegram 
Telegram: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=06a4635e9e178a911a3d0d012c248d320596ea7b, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

```bash
[amirreza@localhost Telegram]$ ldd Telegram 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe9b9c1000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9c9779c000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9c97743000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f9c976f9000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f9c97637000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f9c97621000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f9c97599000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f9c9756b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9c97424000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f9c9741f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9c972f5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9c972ee000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9c971a8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9c97184000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9c96fba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9c979a2000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9c96fb4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9c96f9a000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f9c96f3a000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9c96f0d000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9c96ef1000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f9c96ee6000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9c96eb7000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f9c96ea4000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f9c96e6d000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f9c96db4000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib64/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f9c96d7e000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f9c96d69000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9c96d63000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f9c96cea000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f9c96c97000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9c96c8a000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f9c96bf1000)
```

PS:
I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1554556/nnn-file-manager-image-opens-in-web-browser) question and it didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, most applications should be in directories that are in your `$PATH`, and so you should not need to run executable from the current directory very often.

It seems `nnn` does not have a "run this executable" function.

You probably should link or move the executable to a directory that is listed in your `$PATH` environment variable, and then you should be able to run it with `nnn`'s "Launch app" key (default `=`) from any directory, just by specifying the name `Telegram` without any path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not work. The file has execute permission. I can execute it in a gui file manager by double clicking on it.

Comment: Or run in terminal by `./Telegram`

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I created a link to Telegram launcher in the in one of my `$PATH` dirs. But still when try to open Telegram from `nnn`, the firefox is launched.